# Linq/Enumerable Any Vs Contains

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

I've solved a problem I was having but although I've found out how something works (or doesn't) I'm not clear on why.

As I'm the type of person who likes to know the "why" I'm hoping someone can explain:

I have list of items and associated comments, and I wanted to differentiate between admin comments and user comments, so I tried the following code:

```
User commentUser = userRepository.GetUserById(comment.userId);
Role commentUserRole = context.Roles.Single(x=>x.Name == "admin");
if(commentUser.Roles.Contains(commentUserRole)
 {
   //do stuff
 }
else
{
 // do other stuff
}
```

Stepping through the code showed that although it had the correct Role object, it didn't recognise the role in the commentUser.Roles

The code that eventually worked is:

```
if(commentUser.Roles.Any(x=>x.Name == "admin"))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

I'm happy with this because it's less code and in my opinion cleaner, but I don't understand how contains didn't work.

Hoping someone can clear that up for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **probably** because you didn't override the equality comparisons (`Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `operator==`) on your `Role` class. Therefore, it was doing reference comparison, which really isn't the best idea, as if they're not the same object, it makes it think it's a different. You need to override those equality operators to provide value equality.

Comment: I don't get it - isn't User.Roles a list of Role objects?

Comment: Since he didn't use `==` between Role object, it wasn't important if he overloaded `operator ==`, but you are right about overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @richardterris It's all down to how your object context deals with a second request for the same object.  It looks like the behaviour is to create a new object rather than returning the already requested object.  This means that even though all the property values come out the same, they are in fact different objects and without an equality override the value returns false.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Just for consistency: I know he doesn't need it in this example.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override `Equals` (and always also  `GetHashCode` then) if you want to use `Contains`. Otherwise `Equals` will just compare references.

So for example:

```
public class Role
{
    public string RoleName{ get; set; }
    public int RoleID{ get; set; }
    // ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Role r2 = obj as Role;
        if (r2 == null) return false;
        return RoleID == r2.RoleID;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return RoleID;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return RoleName;
    } 
}
```

Another option is to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Role>` for the overload of [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx):

```
public class RoleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Role>
{
    public bool Equals(Role x, Role y)
    {
        return x.RoleID.Equals(y.RoleID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Role obj)
    {
        return obj.RoleID;
    }
}
```

Use it in this way:

```
var comparer = new RoleComparer();
User commentUser = userRepository.GetUserById(comment.userId);
Role commentUserRole = context.Roles.Single(x=>x.Name == "admin");
if(commentUser.Roles.Contains(commentUserRole, comparer))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Of course if `Role` is a class that is not `sealed`, some people prefer to use `return GetType() == r2.GetType() && RoleID == r2.RoleID;`. Otherwise it will be difficult (even for careful coders) to derive from `Role` and get _their_ `Equals` correct.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I've already added another option, he can use a `IEqualityComparer<Role>`. On that way he didn't need to modify `Role` itself.

Comment: I like that. My comment is only relevant for your first "option", modifying the `Role` type itself, and since you haven't deleted that option from your answer, I still feel like commenting on that.

Comment: I suppose the question is, is this better than just using .Any to check the name?

Comment: @richardterris: Not necessarily, it's all about readability: If you need this class often and you need to compare roles often with each other(f.e. in `Enumerable.Contains`) it is better to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. That's best practise anyway if you can modify the class. If you can't you could still use a custom `IEqualityComparer` as shown above. Then you can even use the comparer in  other linq methods like `GroupBy`, `Intersect`,`Distinct`, `Join`, etc.. All of these methods have an overloaded version for an `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you can't override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`.

Comment: Yes good point! In my situation this is the only place where I have to do this and therefore .Any is best. I think if I was having to do a lot of this then I would change the Role class.

Comment: In the other places where I'm checking roles, I'd be checking the current logged in user so I can use User.IsInRole but here I'm checking the user who posted the comment. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It will be your equality comparison for a Role.

The object in `commentUserRole` is not the same object as the one you are looking for `commentUser.Roles`.

Your context object will create a new object when you select from it and populate your Roles property with a collection of new Roles.  If your context is not tracking the objects in order to return the same object when a second copy is requested then it will be a different object even though all the properties may be the same. Hence the failure of Contains

Your `Any` clause is explicitly checking the Name property which is why it works

Try making Role implement `IEquatable<Role>`

```
public class Role : IEquatable<Role> {
  public bool Equals(Role compare) {
    return compare != null && this.Name == compare.Name;
  }
}
```

Whilst [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) shows you only need this for a `List<T>` you may actually need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make this work

in which case:

```
public class Role : IEquatable<Role> {
  public bool Equals(Role compare) {
    return compare != null && this.Name == compare.Name;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object compare) {
     return this.Equals(compare as Role); // this will call the above equals method
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
     return this.Name == null ? 0 : this.Name.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've commented on 'It'sNotALie''s comment - but I think you're both saying pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When using the `Contains`-method, you check if the the array `Roles` of the user-object contains the object you have retrieved from the database beforehand. Though the array contains an object for the role "admin" it does not contain the exact object you fetched before.

When using the `Any`-method you check if there is any role having the name "admin" - and that delivers the expected result.

To get the same result with the `Contains`-method implement the `IEquatable<Role>`-interface on the role-class and compare the name to check whether two instances have actually the same value.